Empty output job folder
I have setup local JupyterLab instance with SageMaker extension in order to run jobs in the AWS and now I see that jobs are started with proper .ipynb file in the input S3 folder but do not see any result because no files with "output" prefix exist and nothing to download.
Everything is configured following this manual. Roles, permission are double checked and I have run out of ideas. Could you give me a direction? Do we have any relevant logs to have a glance under the hood?
Update 1
Full scenario:

Create IAM User (name: lab)
Create inline policy for this user (name: LabPolicy)

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "EventBridgeSchedule",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "events:TagResource",
                "events:DeleteRule",
                "events:PutTargets",
                "events:DescribeRule",
                "events:EnableRule",
                "events:PutRule",
                "events:RemoveTargets",
                "events:DisableRule"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:ResourceTag/sagemaker:is-scheduling-notebook-job": "true"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "IAMPassRoleToNotebookJob",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iam:PassRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:role/SagemakerJupyterScheduler*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "iam:PassedToService": [
                        "sagemaker.amazonaws.com",
                        "events.amazonaws.com"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "IAMListRoles",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iam:ListRoles",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "S3ArtifactsAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutEncryptionConfiguration",
                "s3:CreateBucket",
                "s3:PutBucketVersioning",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetEncryptionConfiguration",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::sagemaker-automated-execution-*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "S3DriverAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::sagemakerheadlessexecution-*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "SagemakerJobs",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sagemaker:DescribeTrainingJob",
                "sagemaker:StopTrainingJob",
                "sagemaker:DescribePipeline",
                "sagemaker:CreateTrainingJob",
                "sagemaker:DeletePipeline",
                "sagemaker:CreatePipeline"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:ResourceTag/sagemaker:is-scheduling-notebook-job": "true"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowSearch",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sagemaker:Search",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "SagemakerTags",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sagemaker:ListTags",
                "sagemaker:AddTags"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:sagemaker:*:*:pipeline/*",
                "arn:aws:sagemaker:*:*:space/*",
                "arn:aws:sagemaker:*:*:training-job/*",
                "arn:aws:sagemaker:*:*:user-profile/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "ECRImage",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}


Create IAM Role (name: SagemakerJupyterSchedulerRole)
Replace the existing trust policy

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": [
                    "sagemaker.amazonaws.com",
                    "events.amazonaws.com"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}


Attach AmazonSageMakerFullAccess
Create and Attach execution policy (name: SagemakerJupyterSchedulerExecutionPolicy)

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::sagemaker-automated-execution-xxxxxxxxxxxx-us-east-1/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:CreateBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:GetBucketCors",
                "s3:PutBucketCors"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketAcl",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::sagemaker-automated-execution-xxxxxxxxxxxx-us-east-1"
            ]
        }
    ]
}


Job Options

Image: arn:aws:sagemaker:us-east-1:081325390199:image/sagemaker-base-python-38
Kernel: python3
Role ARN: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/SagemakerJupyterSchedulerRole
Input: s3://sagemaker-automated-execution-xxxxxxxxxxxx-us-east-1/
Output: s3://sagemaker-automated-execution-xxxxxxxxxxxx-us-east-1/


Run!

Eventually, I see just input ipynb-files in the target S3 bucket
❯ aws s3 ls s3://sagemaker-automated-execution-xxxxxxxxxxxx-us-east-1/ --recursive
2024-04-18 16:57:19       4536 helloworld2ipynb-helloworld2-45e83409-2024-04-18-16-57-17/input/hello-world2.ipynb
2024-04-18 16:49:00       4536 helloworld2ipynb-helloworld2-4d179d7f-2024-04-18-16-48-57/input/hello-world2.ipynb
2024-04-15 11:31:10       4536 helloworld2ipynb-helloworld2-ae714726-2024-04-15-11-31-08/input/hello-world2.ipynb
2024-04-15 10:47:33       2631 helloworld2ipynb-helloworld2-b516481a-2024-04-15-10-47-31/input/hello-world2.ipynb

Update 2
@Tomonori Shimomura gave an idea to make an experiment and eventually I have realised that job is not run by SageMaker at all!
Now need to mention one step back and my previous question on the StackOverflow where I came up with my own "solution", but now it seems that my current issue somehow related to that hack.
Update 3
I put to the resource-metadata.json:
{
    "AppType": "JupyterLab"
}

... because I had found in the
amazon_sagemaker_jupyter_scheduler/model_converter.py:
if get_app_type() == "JupyterLab":
    container_entrypoint = ["amazon_sagemaker_scheduler"]
else:
    container_entrypoint = ["/bin/bash"]

Now job starts but fails immediately with error: "[FATAL tini (8)] exec amazon_sagemaker_scheduler failed: No such file or directory"
I am trying to figure it out, but don't have any ideas yet.
Final Update
I have missed strict version requirements in the manual and was trying to use different versions from 3rd branch. Fortunately, @Tomonori-san have noticed my mistake.
Though, need to mention that not everything has started to work as expected right after the downgrade because I had faced with GetBucketLocation issue and just after several hours of debugging aiobotocore and amazon-sagemaker-jupyter-scheduler extensions I have finally realised that S3 bucket has to be hosted somewhere else rather than us-east-1 because LocationConstraint of such buckets is null what affects logic in amazon_sagemaker_jupyter_scheduler/clients.py
(base) lab4:~$ aws s3api get-bucket-location --bucket sagemaker-automated-execution-xxxxxxxxxxxx-us-east-2
{
    "LocationConstraint": "us-east-2"
}
(base) lab4:~$ aws s3api get-bucket-location --bucket sagemaker-automated-execution-xxxxxxxxxxxx-us-east-1
{
    "LocationConstraint": null
}


This issue is because of the manually added resource-metadata.json.
Please check the answer in your previous post for the solution to avoid "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/ml/metadata/resource-metadata.json'" error, and you can revert your hacks.

I just followed the blog post and I was able to run a notebook job successfully.
If you successfully run the job, you will see following files under the S3 bucket you specified.
$ aws s3 ls s3://sagemaker-automated-execution-123456789012-us-east-2 --recursive
2024-04-17 17:57:49       9480 notebookjobtestip-notebookjobtest-bf50211d-2024-04-18-00-57-47/input/notebook-job-test.ipynb
2024-04-17 18:00:14      13948 notebookjobtestip-notebookjobtest-bf50211d-2024-04-18-00-57-47/output/output.tar.gz

I am sharing my input configurations:

Compute type : ml.m5.large
Image : arn:aws:sagemaker:us-east-2:429704687514:image/sagemaker-base-python-38
Kernel : python3
arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/SagemakerJupyterSchedulerRole
Input Folder : s3://sagemaker-automated-execution-123456789012-us-east-2/
Output Folder : s3://sagemaker-automated-execution-123456789012-us-east-2/

Please try similar configurations and check if it works.

Thank you, for reaching me out at the both places :) I have updated my answer with all steps, could you come along with me and compare with yours?

One difference I found is, I only attached AmazonSageMakerFullAccess to the SagemakerJupyterSchedulerRole. I don't think it is related to the issue you are seeing because your SagemakerJupyterSchedulerExecutionPolicy is only allowing additional permissions. AmazonSageMakerFullAccess should have permission to read/write to S3 buckets which contain "sagemaker" keyword in the backet name.

To isolate the issue, if you upload some file to the S3 bucket from the notebook itself (with aws s3 command or boto3), does it succeed?

Arigato @Tomonori - the actual problem is bigger than I have thought. Could you check the second update out and lookup up for resource-metadata.json file  at /opt/ml/metadata : exists or not? empty or not? Thank you!

I will add another answer for the root cause
